# Displaying hidden DIVs vs fetching content via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am using [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox) to display menus/dialogues to users of an app I am building. The content displayed in the box is HTML - I could generate it all in JS and put it into a hidden div to display when needed, or make an AJAX call to fetch the content when a fancyBox is opened.

Is there any downside to having a bunch of hidden divs in a page (performance issues on mobile browsers etc)? I'd prefer to do it this way as the user experience is obviously going to be snappier.

Comment: Logically speaking I think ajax would be a better call, since it's loading specific data instead of populating it all at once. I doubt it really makes a difference in overhead, but if the app gets huge, it could save some load time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should load information as soon as you can as the time to complete requests is the main bottleneck in most web apps. The issue here is not so much the html but the assets that are requested in addition to the html (e.g. images, videos, etc). These take up memory and also, potentially slow down the initial page load time as you could be blocking visible image loads by loading images that are not (yet) visible. To work out if either of these issues is a problem you don't really have any alternative but to test on your target devices. However, in your case you don't actually save any memory by fetching the assets later as they are still ultimately being fetched at some point and so the browser is going to have to be able to cope with everything being loaded in the end - therefore you might as well have them in the beginning. If page load times are an issue you could still defer loading the assets but  only until the dom has rendered rather than waiting until the hidden div is needed. That way you don't hold up the page load but still have the assets when you need them. For example in JQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#hiddenDiv').html(hiddenContent);
});
```

The assets (images, etc) will not be requested until the html referencing them has been added to the dom.

Comment: Thanks, this is quite interesting. My content is HTML only, there are no external resources - but duly noted for next time. :-)